# undefined reference to function in c++

Tags: c++, stm32f4discovery, libopencm3

I did search and none of the answers really explained what I am seeing.

I had a file that was compiling correctly, and added a new include:

```
#include "libopencm3/stm32/usart.h"
```

Compile again and fine. Now, I add a function:

```
void usart_setup(void)
{
    /* Setup USART6 parameters. */
    usart_set_baudrate(USART6, 38400);
    usart_set_databits(USART6, 8);
    usart_set_stopbits(USART6, USART_STOPBITS_1);
    usart_set_mode(USART6, USART_MODE_TX);
    usart_set_parity(USART6, USART_PARITY_NONE);
    usart_set_flow_control(USART6, USART_FLOWCONTROL_NONE);

    /* Finally enable the USART. */
    usart_enable(USART6);
}
```

Now I get:

```
/home/troy/projects/131114troy/tests/gpio1/trunk/gpio.c:137: undefined reference to `usart_set_baudrate'
/home/troy/projects/131114troy/tests/gpio1/trunk/gpio.c:138: undefined reference to `usart_set_databits'
/home/troy/projects/131114troy/tests/gpio1/trunk/gpio.c:139: undefined reference to `usart_set_stopbits'
/home/troy/projects/131114troy/tests/gpio1/trunk/gpio.c:140: undefined reference to `usart_set_mode'
/home/troy/projects/131114troy/tests/gpio1/trunk/gpio.c:141: undefined reference to `usart_set_parity'
/home/troy/projects/131114troy/tests/gpio1/trunk/gpio.c:142: undefined reference to `usart_set_flow_control'
/home/troy/projects/131114troy/tests/gpio1/trunk/gpio.c:145: undefined reference to `usart_enable'
```

Here is the usart.h file:

```
/*
 * This file is part of the libopencm3 project.
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2009 Uwe Hermann <uwe@hermann-uwe.de>
 *
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

#ifndef LIBOPENCM3_USART_H
#define LIBOPENCM3_USART_H

#include <libopencm3/stm32/memorymap.h>
#include <libopencm3/cm3/common.h>

/* --- Convenience macros -------------------------------------------------- */

#define USART1              USART1_BASE
#define USART2              USART2_BASE
#define USART3              USART3_BASE
#define UART4               UART4_BASE
#define UART5               UART5_BASE
#define USART6              USART6_BASE

/* --- USART registers ----------------------------------------------------- */

/* Status register (USARTx_SR) */
#define USART_SR(usart_base)        MMIO32(usart_base + 0x00)
#define USART1_SR           USART_SR(USART1_BASE)
#define USART2_SR           USART_SR(USART2_BASE)
#define USART3_SR           USART_SR(USART3_BASE)
#define UART4_SR            USART_SR(UART4_BASE)
#define UART5_SR            USART_SR(UART5_BASE)
#define USART6_SR           USART_SR(USART6_BASE)

/* Data register (USARTx_DR) */
#define USART_DR(usart_base)        MMIO32(usart_base + 0x04)
#define USART1_DR           USART_DR(USART1_BASE)
#define USART2_DR           USART_DR(USART2_BASE)
#define USART3_DR           USART_DR(USART3_BASE)
#define UART4_DR            USART_DR(UART4_BASE)
#define UART5_DR            USART_DR(UART5_BASE)
#define USART6_DR           USART_DR(USART6_BASE)

/* Baud rate register (USARTx_BRR) */
#define USART_BRR(usart_base)       MMIO32(usart_base + 0x08)
#define USART1_BRR          USART_BRR(USART1_BASE)
#define USART2_BRR          USART_BRR(USART2_BASE)
#define USART3_BRR          USART_BRR(USART3_BASE)
#define UART4_BRR           USART_BRR(UART4_BASE)
#define UART5_BRR           USART_BRR(UART5_BASE)
#define USART6_BRR          USART_BRR(USART6_BASE)

/* Control register 1 (USARTx_CR1) */
#define USART_CR1(usart_base)       MMIO32(usart_base + 0x0c)
#define USART1_CR1          USART_CR1(USART1_BASE)
#define USART2_CR1          USART_CR1(USART2_BASE)
#define USART3_CR1          USART_CR1(USART3_BASE)
#define UART4_CR1           USART_CR1(UART4_BASE)
#define UART5_CR1           USART_CR1(UART5_BASE)
#define USART6_CR1          USART_CR1(USART6_BASE)

/* Control register 2 (USARTx_CR2) */
#define USART_CR2(usart_base)       MMIO32(usart_base + 0x10)
#define USART1_CR2          USART_CR2(USART1_BASE)
#define USART2_CR2          USART_CR2(USART2_BASE)
#define USART3_CR2          USART_CR2(USART3_BASE)
#define UART4_CR2           USART_CR2(UART4_BASE)
#define UART5_CR2           USART_CR2(UART5_BASE)
#define USART6_CR2          USART_CR2(USART6_BASE)

/* Control register 3 (USARTx_CR3) */
#define USART_CR3(usart_base)       MMIO32(usart_base + 0x14)
#define USART1_CR3          USART_CR3(USART1_BASE)
#define USART2_CR3          USART_CR3(USART2_BASE)
#define USART3_CR3          USART_CR3(USART3_BASE)
#define UART4_CR3           USART_CR3(UART4_BASE)
#define UART5_CR3           USART_CR3(UART5_BASE)
#define USART6_CR3          USART_CR3(USART6_BASE)

/* Guard time and prescaler register (USARTx_GTPR) */
#define USART_GTPR(usart_base)      MMIO32(usart_base + 0x18)
#define USART1_GTPR         USART_GTPR(USART1_BASE)
#define USART2_GTPR         USART_GTPR(USART2_BASE)
#define USART3_GTPR         USART_GTPR(USART3_BASE)
#define UART4_GTPR          USART_GTPR(UART4_BASE)
#define UART5_GTPR          USART_GTPR(UART5_BASE)
#define USART6_GTPR         USART_GTPR(USART6_BASE)

/* --- USART_SR values ----------------------------------------------------- */

/* CTS: CTS flag */
/* Note: N/A on UART4/5 */
#define USART_SR_CTS            (1 << 9)

/* LBD: LIN break detection flag */
#define USART_SR_LBD            (1 << 8)

/* TXE: Transmit data buffer empty */
#define USART_SR_TXE            (1 << 7)

/* TC: Transmission complete */
#define USART_SR_TC         (1 << 6)

/* RXNE: Read data register not empty */
#define USART_SR_RXNE           (1 << 5)

/* IDLE: Idle line detected */
#define USART_SR_IDLE           (1 << 4)

/* ORE: Overrun error */
#define USART_SR_ORE            (1 << 3)

/* NE: Noise error flag */
#define USART_SR_NE         (1 << 2)

/* FE: Framing error */
#define USART_SR_FE         (1 << 1)

/* PE: Parity error */
#define USART_SR_PE         (1 << 0)

/* --- USART_DR values ----------------------------------------------------- */

/* USART_DR[8:0]: DR[8:0]: Data value */
#define USART_DR_MASK                   0x1FF

/* --- USART_BRR values ---------------------------------------------------- */

/* DIV_Mantissa[11:0]: mantissa of USARTDIV */
#define USART_BRR_DIV_MANTISSA_MASK     (0xFFF << 4)
/* DIV_Fraction[3:0]: fraction of USARTDIV */
#define USART_BRR_DIV_FRACTION_MASK     0xF

/* --- USART_CR1 values ---------------------------------------------------- */

/* UE: USART enable */
#define USART_CR1_UE            (1 << 13)

/* M: Word length */
#define USART_CR1_M         (1 << 12)

/* WAKE: Wakeup method */
#define USART_CR1_WAKE          (1 << 11)

/* PCE: Parity control enable */
#define USART_CR1_PCE           (1 << 10)

/* PS: Parity selection */
#define USART_CR1_PS            (1 << 9)

/* PEIE: PE interrupt enable */
#define USART_CR1_PEIE          (1 << 8)

/* TXEIE: TXE interrupt enable */
#define USART_CR1_TXEIE         (1 << 7)

/* TCIE: Transmission complete interrupt enable */
#define USART_CR1_TCIE          (1 << 6)

/* RXNEIE: RXNE interrupt enable */
#define USART_CR1_RXNEIE        (1 << 5)

/* IDLEIE: IDLE interrupt enable */
#define USART_CR1_IDLEIE        (1 << 4)

/* TE: Transmitter enable */
#define USART_CR1_TE            (1 << 3)

/* RE: Receiver enable */
#define USART_CR1_RE            (1 << 2)

/* RWU: Receiver wakeup */
#define USART_CR1_RWU           (1 << 1)

/* SBK: Send break */
#define USART_CR1_SBK           (1 << 0)

/* --- USART_CR2 values ---------------------------------------------------- */

/* LINEN: LIN mode enable */
#define USART_CR2_LINEN         (1 << 14)

/* STOP[13:12]: STOP bits */
#define USART_CR2_STOPBITS_1        (0x00 << 12)     /* 1 stop bit */
#define USART_CR2_STOPBITS_0_5      (0x01 << 12)     /* 0.5 stop bits */
#define USART_CR2_STOPBITS_2        (0x02 << 12)     /* 2 stop bits */
#define USART_CR2_STOPBITS_1_5      (0x03 << 12)     /* 1.5 stop bits */
#define USART_CR2_STOPBITS_MASK         (0x03 << 12)
#define USART_CR2_STOPBITS_SHIFT        12

/* CLKEN: Clock enable */
#define USART_CR2_CLKEN         (1 << 11)

/* CPOL: Clock polarity */
#define USART_CR2_CPOL          (1 << 10)

/* CPHA: Clock phase */
#define USART_CR2_CPHA          (1 << 9)

/* LBCL: Last bit clock pulse */
#define USART_CR2_LBCL          (1 << 8)

/* LBDIE: LIN break detection interrupt enable */
#define USART_CR2_LBDIE         (1 << 6)

/* LBDL: LIN break detection length */
#define USART_CR2_LBDL          (1 << 5)

/* ADD[3:0]: Addres of the usart node */
#define USART_CR2_ADD_MASK              0xF

/* --- USART_CR3 values ---------------------------------------------------- */

/* CTSIE: CTS interrupt enable */
/* Note: N/A on UART4 & UART5 */
#define USART_CR3_CTSIE         (1 << 10)

/* CTSE: CTS enable */
/* Note: N/A on UART4 & UART5 */
#define USART_CR3_CTSE          (1 << 9)

/* RTSE: RTS enable */
/* Note: N/A on UART4 & UART5 */
#define USART_CR3_RTSE          (1 << 8)

/* DMAT: DMA enable transmitter */
/* Note: N/A on UART5 */
#define USART_CR3_DMAT          (1 << 7)

/* DMAR: DMA enable receiver */
/* Note: N/A on UART5 */
#define USART_CR3_DMAR          (1 << 6)

/* SCEN: Smartcard mode enable */
/* Note: N/A on UART4 & UART5 */
#define USART_CR3_SCEN          (1 << 5)

/* NACK: Smartcard NACK enable */
/* Note: N/A on UART4 & UART5 */
#define USART_CR3_NACK          (1 << 4)

/* HDSEL: Half-duplex selection */
#define USART_CR3_HDSEL         (1 << 3)

/* IRLP: IrDA low-power */
#define USART_CR3_IRLP          (1 << 2)

/* IREN: IrDA mode enable */
#define USART_CR3_IREN          (1 << 1)

/* EIE: Error interrupt enable */
#define USART_CR3_EIE           (1 << 0)

/* --- USART_GTPR values --------------------------------------------------- */

/* GT[7:0]: Guard time value */
/* Note: N/A on UART4 & UART5 */
#define USART_GTPR_GT_MASK              (0xFF << 8)

/* PSC[7:0]: Prescaler value */
/* Note: N/A on UART4/5 */
#define USART_GTPR_PSC_MASK             0xFF

/* TODO */ /* Note to Uwe: what needs to be done here? */

/* --- Convenience defines ------------------------------------------------- */

/* CR1_PCE / CR1_PS combined values */
#define USART_PARITY_NONE       0x00
#define USART_PARITY_ODD        USART_CR1_PS
#define USART_PARITY_EVEN       (USART_CR1_PS | USART_CR1_PCE)
#define USART_PARITY_MASK       (USART_CR1_PS | USART_CR1_PCE)

/* CR1_TE/CR1_RE combined values */
#define USART_MODE_RX                   USART_CR1_RE
#define USART_MODE_TX               USART_CR1_TE
#define USART_MODE_TX_RX        (USART_CR1_RE | USART_CR1_TE)
#define USART_MODE_MASK             (USART_CR1_RE | USART_CR1_TE)

#define USART_STOPBITS_1        USART_CR2_STOPBITS_1   /* 1 stop bit */
#define USART_STOPBITS_0_5      USART_CR2_STOPBITS_0_5 /* 0.5 stop bits */
#define USART_STOPBITS_2        USART_CR2_STOPBITS_2   /* 2 stop bits */
#define USART_STOPBITS_1_5      USART_CR2_STOPBITS_1_5 /* 1.5 stop bits */

/* CR3_CTSE/CR3_RTSE combined values */
#define USART_FLOWCONTROL_NONE          0x00
#define USART_FLOWCONTROL_RTS           USART_CR3_RTSE
#define USART_FLOWCONTROL_CTS           USART_CR3_CTSE
#define USART_FLOWCONTROL_RTS_CTS   (USART_CR3_RTSE | USART_CR3_CTSE)
#define USART_FLOWCONTROL_MASK          (USART_CR3_RTSE | USART_CR3_CTSE)

/* --- Function prototypes ------------------------------------------------- */

void usart_set_baudrate(u32 usart, u32 baud);
void usart_set_databits(u32 usart, u32 bits);
void usart_set_stopbits(u32 usart, u32 stopbits);
void usart_set_parity(u32 usart, u32 parity);
void usart_set_mode(u32 usart, u32 mode);
void usart_set_flow_control(u32 usart, u32 flowcontrol);
void usart_enable(u32 usart);
void usart_disable(u32 usart);
void usart_send(u32 usart, u16 data);
u16 usart_recv(u32 usart);
void usart_wait_send_ready(u32 usart);
void usart_wait_recv_ready(u32 usart);
void usart_send_blocking(u32 usart, u16 data);
u16 usart_recv_blocking(u32 usart);
void usart_enable_rx_dma(u32 usart);
void usart_disable_rx_dma(u32 usart);
void usart_enable_tx_dma(u32 usart);
void usart_disable_tx_dma(u32 usart);

#endif
```

If I comment out the line `void usart_set_baudrate(u32 usart, u32 baud);` I get an additional warning:

```
gpio.c:137:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'usart_set_baudrate'
```

So it seems to be picking up the function at least in some way. Somewhat new to c++ so not too sure what else I can try. Any pointers?

Makefile:

```
# Name of the .c file with 'main' as well as output file name
NAME    = gpio

# Linker file
LDFILE  =stm32_flash.ld

# Current directory
CURDIR=.

SRCS = $(NAME).c startup_stm32f4xx.s syscalls.c 

###################################################

# Check for valid float argument
# NOTE that you have to run make clean after
# changing these as hardfloat and softfloat are not
# binary compatible
ifneq ($(FLOAT_TYPE), hard)
ifneq ($(FLOAT_TYPE), soft)
override FLOAT_TYPE = soft
endif
endif

###################################################
# Prefix the name for the particular toolchain
PREFIX      = arm-none-eabi-

TOOLDIR =~/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin
CC  =$(TOOLDIR)/$(PREFIX)gcc
LD  =$(TOOLDIR)/$(PREFIX)ld
OBJCOPY =$(TOOLDIR)/$(PREFIX)objcopy
SIZE    =$(TOOLDIR)/$(PREFIX)size
OBJDUMP =$(TOOLDIR)/$(PREFIX)objdump

CFLAGS  = -std=gnu99 -g -Os -Wall
CFLAGS += -mlittle-endian -mthumb -mthumb-interwork -nostartfiles -mcpu=cortex-m4

ifeq ($(FLOAT_TYPE), hard)
CFLAGS += -fsingle-precision-constant -Wdouble-promotion
CFLAGS += -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard
else
CFLAGS += -msoft-float
endif

###################################################

# Directory path--includes for .h and .c files common to all routines
LIBCOMMONALL      = $(CURDIR)/../../../common_all/trunk

# Navigation to libraries specific to the f4 and discoveryf4
LIBF4D      = $(CURDIR)/../../../sw_discoveryf4/trunk

# Routes to USB 
LIBUSB      = $(LIBF4D)/STM32F4_USB_CDC

# Includes--ST USB
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBUSB)/inc
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBUSB)/inc/StdPeriph/inc
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBUSB)/lib/StdPeriph/inc
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBUSB)/lib/USB_OTG/inc
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBUSB)/inc/USB_Device/Core/inc
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBUSB)/inc/USB_Device/Class/cdc/inc
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBUSB)/lib/Core/stm32
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBUSB)/lib/Core/cmsis
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBUSB)/lib/USB_Device/Class/cdc/inc
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBUSB)/lib/USB_Device/Core/inc/

# Includes--our stuff
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBCOMMONALL)
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBF4D)/lib/libdiscoveryf4
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBF4D)/lib/libmiscstm32f4 
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBF4D)/lib/libusartstm32f4
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBF4D)/lib

# Library paths--ST USB
LIBPATHS  = -L$(LIBUSB)
LIBPATHS += -L$(LIBUSB)/lib/StdPeriph
LIBPATHS += -L$(LIBUSB)/lib/USB_Device/Core
LIBPATHS += -L$(LIBUSB)/lib/USB_Device/Class/cdc
LIBPATHS += -L$(LIBUSB)/lib/USB_OTG

# Library paths--our stuff
LIBPATHS += -L$(LIBF4D)/lib/libdiscoveryf4
LIBPATHS += -L$(LIBF4D)/lib/libmiscstm32f4 
LIBPATHS += -L$(LIBCOMMONALL)/stm32

# Libraries to link
#   USB
LIBS     = -lm -lusbf4 -lstdperiph -lusbdevcdc -lusbcore -lusbdevcore  -lusbf4  -lstdperiph
#   our stuff
LIBS    += -ldiscoveryf4 -lmiscstm32f4 

LDFLAGS  = -T$(LDFILE)

OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

###################################################

.PHONY: proj

all: proj
    $(SIZE) $(NAME).elf

proj:   $(NAME).elf

$(NAME).elf: $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBPATHS) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex   $(NAME).elf $(NAME).hex
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(NAME).elf $(NAME).bin
    $(OBJDUMP) -S $(NAME).elf > $(NAME).list

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(NAME).elf
    rm -f $(NAME).hex
    rm -f $(NAME).bin
#   $(MAKE) clean -C lib # Remove this line if you don't want to clean the libs as well

flash: images
    @printf "  FLASHING   $(NAME)\n"
    @# IMPORTANT: Don't use "resume", only "reset" will work correctly!
    # Kill running instances of the server
#   killall st-util
    st-flash write $(NAME).bin 0x08000000

.PHONY: images clean
```

Comment: You're missing to *link* with a library or other source/object file.

Comment: seems a linker problem. You have the .h file and functions declared in the file, but the real implementation library is missing.

Comment: Show us your makefile

Comment: You didn't _read_ the answers that came up from your search.

Comment: In your .h  file I am not able to find defination for `USART6_BASE`. It may be a problem.

Comment: @Vijay I added the makefile. I dont see anything in there linking the `#include "libopencm3/stm32/f4/gpio.h"` file either but those seem to be working alright.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not linking against a library that has the *definition* of those functions. usart.h is only providing the *declarations*, which tells the compiler the function(s) exist, but not what they actually do. It's the definitions that accomplish that. I imagine there's a usart.lib (or something similarly named) somewhere that needs to be added to your list of linked-in libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is because you are not linking to the library.
make sure you have these three things in your make file:

```
-I header file path
-L library path
-llibraryname
```

these three things should be supplied as arguments to your compiler.